# How can I use templates to normalize number in range from 0 to 1?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm designing a class which is RGB color representation.
It has three properties: red, green and blue.

Until now, I had those 3 properties in type **unsigned char int** (from 0 to 255). I'd like to use C++ templates, so I could also use other types, like **float**, **double** or **int**.

However, I need to know the maximum value, which probably could be solved with std::numeric_limits. The problem are floating point numbers. They should be in range 0..1. Do you have any ideas how to hack this problem?

My goal is to be able convert red, green and blue from not known type into number 0..1.

Comment: Template specialization with std::is_floating_point, only accepting values between 0 and 1 for the RGB values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T>
RGBClass {
public:
    RGBClass():
        max_value(std::numberic_limits<T>::max())
        /* ... */
    {}
    /* ... */
    const T max_value;

private:
    T R_;
    T G_;
    T B_;
};

template<>
RGBClass<float> {
public: 
    RGBClass():
        max_value(1),
        /* ... */
    {}

    // convert other type to float 0..1
    template<class OTHER_TYPE>
    RGBClass(const OTHER_TYPE& other):
        max_value(1),
        R_((float)other.R_ / (float)other.max_value),
        /* ... */
    {}
    const float max_value;

private:
    float R_;
    float G_;
    float B_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T, typename=void>
struct pixel_component_range {
  static constexpr T max() { return std::numberic_limits<T>::max(); }
};
template<typename F>
struct pixel_component_range<F, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<F>::value>::type>
{
  static constexpr T max() { return 1.f; }
};
```

now `pixel_component_range<T>::max()` evaluates to the max value of integers, and `1.` for floating point values.